# What is the difference between domain and URL property performance in Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console

Our site has been rebuilt, previously it was using NextJS/SanityCMS, now it is using WordPress.

In `Google Search Console` > **domain property**> `Search Results` > add a filter for the `Query` being our top search term, **our performance has stayed roughly the same**.

In `Google Search Console` > **URL property** (`https://example.com`) > `Search Results` > add a filter for the `Query` being our top search term, **our performance has tanked / is much worse**.

I'm puzzled and concerned by this.

**What reasons might there be between the performance of the domain property and the URL property?**

Comment: Have you looked at specific pages within both properties? Are they ranking similarly between them? Are the 'tanked' pages of a different protocol (www vs. non-www)?

Answer (score 1):

A domain property in Google Search Console shows data for all the hosts within the domain and an URL property will only show data for URLs starting with the name / value of the URL property.

The Domain Propery `example.com` includes:

```
http://example.com/
https://example.com/
http://example.com/foo
https://example.com/foo
http://subdomain.example.com/
https://subdomain.example.com/
http://subdomain.example.com/foo
https://subdomain.example.com/foo
```

The URL property `https://example.com` includes

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/foo
```

The URL property `https://example.com/` does not include

```
http://example.com/ (different protocol)
https://subdomain.example.com/ (different host)
```

The URL property `https://example.com/directory/` includes

```
https://example.com/directory/
https://example.com/directory/foo
```

The URL property `https://example.com/directory/` does not include

```
https://example.com/ (different directory)
https://example.com/directory-2/ (different directory)
http://example.com/directory/ (different protocol)
https://subdomain.example.com/ (different host)
```

Usually you want to have the domain property and add filters when analyzing changes, but sometimes it is more convinient to have URL properties as they act like a predefined filter. Have a close look at the pages within the domain property to spot the differences and make sure to filter out URLs from the URL property to see the differences between both properties.